# Is form data automatically encoded by browsers?

Tags: forms, urlencode, multipartform-data

I have read [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data) [stuff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) about form data encoding, but one thing remains unclear. In case of enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" we need to urlencode data by hand, [don't we](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1)?

> ... Forms submitted with this content type *must* be encoded as follows

Must be encoded by whom? By browsers? Or by application developers?

The other thing is -- what encoding (if any) is used, or should be used, in case of multipart/form-data?

I'm kindda mislead so big thx in advance.

Comment: That depends on how the POST is being generated.

Comment: Great answer, it all suddenly became so clear, thanks a lot!

Comment: If you set the `enctype` attribute of your form to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the browser will automatically encode the form data. Are you having problems with a browser that doesn't encode the values?

Comment: No, that's the thing - I did not understand who should encode data according to specification. By experimenting I found out that browser makes it, but I still had doubts. But what about multipart/form-data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, browsers url-encode data automatically. And this [w3 docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/) is first of all for those who make browsers. So that phrase, `Forms submitted with this content type must be encoded as follows` means that data should be encoded by browsers. Anyway, one can check it by viewing raw post in the form data handling script (in case of php in looks like `file_get_contents("php://input");`)